Trouble understanding tensor product of Hom set and module
I'm reading Rotman's Advanced Modern Algebra: Part 1 and I'm struggling to understand the following theorem:
Given modules $\left({ }_R X,{ }_R Y_S, Z_S\right)$, where $R$ and $S$ are rings, there is a natural transformation,
$$
\tau_{X, Y, Z}: \operatorname{Hom}_S(Y, Z) \otimes_R X \rightarrow \operatorname{Hom}_S\left(\operatorname{Hom}_R(X, Y), Z\right),
$$
given by
$$
\tau_{X, Y, Z}(f \otimes x): g \mapsto f(g(x))
$$
(where $f \in \operatorname{Hom}_S(Y, Z)$ and $x \in X$ ), which is an isomorphism whenever $X$ is a finitely generated free left $R$-module.
I'm struggling to make sense of the left hand side. How does the tensor product of module $\operatorname{Hom}_S(Y, Z)$ and the module $X$ result in an object whose elemnts are (I assume from the right hand side) $g:X\rightarrow Y $.
I'm new to tensor products so any help clearing this up would be appreciated.

Are these rings unitary?

@julio_es_sui_glace yes

Elements of the tensor product $\hom_S(Y,Z) \otimes_R X$ are linear combinations of $f \otimes x$ where $f$ is an $S$-linear map from $Y$ to $Z$ and $x \in X$.
$\hom_S(Y,Z)$ has a structure of left $R$-module induced by the structure of right module on $Y$. Indeed we have a map $\rho: R^{op} \mapsto \mathrm{End}_{\mathbf{Ab}}(Y)$, which gives us $\rho^* = \hom_S(\rho,Z):R \to \hom_S(Y,Z)$. Hence this tensor product is well defined.
Now your map $\tau_{X,Y,Z}$ eats elements of this tensor product and spits out a morphism of right $S$ modules $\tau_{X,Y,Z}$.
This very morphism $\tau_{X,Y,Z}$ eats a morphism of left $R$-modules $g:X \to Y$ and spits an element of $Z$.
In summary the space where $\tau$ goes is not a module of morphisms but a module of morphisms of morphisms.
One can verify (on tensors) that $\tau(f\otimes_R x)$ is indeed a morphism of $S$-modules:
$$\tau(f \otimes_R x)(g\cdot s)  = f\circ (g\cdot s)(x) = f(g(x) \cdot s) = f(g(x)) \cdot s = (\tau(f\otimes x)(g)) \cdot s $$
Now if $X$ is free and finitely generated, $X = R^{\oplus n}$, so given one morphism
$$\phi: (g:X\to Y) \mapsto \phi(g) \in Z$$
We get $n$ components (one for each copy of $R$ in $X$:
$$\phi_j: g_j \mapsto z_i$$
with $\phi_j:\hom_R(R,Y) \to Z$.
The thing is we have a canonical isomorphism $\hom_R(R,Y) \cong Y$ where  we associate $g:R \to Y$ to $g(1)$ we thus set $\tilde{\phi}_j: Y \to Z$ the associated $S$-linear map. So we can define
$$\begin{array}{rrcl}
\psi :& \hom_S(\hom_R(X,Y),Z)& \to &\hom_S(Y,Z) \otimes_R X \\
& \phi & \mapsto & \sum_{j=1}^n \tilde{\phi}_j \otimes e_j
\end{array}$$
Where $e_j$ is $1_R$ in the j-th copy of $R$ in $X$.
These maps($\tau$ and $\psi$) are clearly inverse of each other so you get your iso!

Thank you I think I understand now.

The point here is that, as $Y$ is an $R$-$S$-bimodule, the hom-set $\mathrm{Hom}_S(Y,Z)$ is naturally a right $R$-module via
$$ (fr)(y) := f(ry) \quad f\in\mathrm{Hom}_S(Y,Z), \quad r\in R, \quad y\in Y. $$
(You should maybe check the details...)
We can therefore form the tensor product $\mathrm{Hom}_S(Y,Z)\otimes_RX$.

Re-reading my post I think I'v mis-worded my question slightly. What I'm not sure about is why the elements of the tensor product seem to be morphisms $g:X\rightarrow Y $.

@ctk They're not. As Julio explains the elements are linear combinations of pure tensors (!) $f\otimes x$ where $f:Y\to Z$ and $x\in X$. However, for $\tau(f\otimes x)$ to make sense as something in $\hom(\hom(X,Y),Z)$, it needs to be a map $\hom(X,Y)\to Z$, right? So it needs to act on elements $g\in\hom(X,Y)$ i.e. it needs to act on morphisms $g:X\to Y$. So $\tau(f\otimes x)$ needs to map such $g$ to elements of $z$; $\tau(f\otimes x):g\mapsto g(f(x))$ then makes sense. You need to check the bilinearity and well-definedness stuff as well of course
